# Avoid duplicate entries in DataGrid from RegEx Matches

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following function that searches a text for an IP and adds it to a DataGrid.

```
try
        {
            string source = e.Result;
            Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+):1400");
            MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(source);

            if (mc.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Match matches in mc)
                {

                    int index = dataGridAllSonos.Columns.ToList().FindIndex(c => c.Header == matches.Groups[1].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine(index);


                    var data = new sonosDevice
                    {
                        sonosIP = matches.Groups[1].Value,
                        sonosName = "XX",
                        sonosRoom = "XX"
                    };

                    dataGridAllSonos.Items.Add(data);


                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                string err = ex.InnerException.Message;
                Console.WriteLine(err);
            }
        }
```

The line `int index = dataGridAllSonos.Columns.ToList().FindIndex(c => c.Header == matches.Groups[1].Value);` is to check if the current found IP (first column) already exists in the DataGrid. It should not be added then.

Unfortunately it returns always `-1` so not found, how can I check if the IP is a duplicate?

**sonosDevice Class**

```
public class sonosDevice
{
    public string sonosIP { get; set; }
    public string sonosName { get; set; }
    public string sonosRoom { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That line will search in the column headers. Is this what you want? You should search in the rows content instead

Comment: You are right I actually look for the column value...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool found = dataGridAllSonos.Items.OfType<string>().Any(i => i == matches.Groups[1].Value);
```